# tournament of 8 people in teams of two, everyone teaming up once and competing twice?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a tournament of 8 people in changing teams of two. 14 games, held at two fields.

f.e.: Field One, Game One: AB vs CD Field Two, Game Two: EF vs GH

Is it possible to mix and team the 8 players so that they each play with everyone else once and against everyone else twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know any abstract algebra, you'll probably want to skip to the end (where I give an actual schedule).

---

Label each player with one of the eight elements of $V=\Bbb{F}_2^3$, the 3-dimensional vector space over the field of 2 elements. We'll write them as three-bit strings (e.g. $100$).

If $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is an ordered basis of $V$, we can use it to specify a pair of games that happen simultaneously.

- If two vectors differ by $e_1$, those two players are on a team.
- If two vectors differ by $e_2$ or $e_2+e_1$, those two players are opponents.
- If two vectors differ by anything involving $e_3$, those two players are in different games.

For example, the basis $\{001, 010, 100\}$ leads to the pair of games where $000$ and $001$ team up against $010$ and $011$, and $100$ and $101$ team up against $110$ and $111$.

Now, notice that the group of linear isomorphisms of $V$, $GL_3(2)$, has elements of order $7$, and that no such element fixes any nonzero vectors (in fact, since there are exactly $7$ nonzero vectors, it must permute all of them cyclically).

One such element is
$$
T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right) \, .
$$

I claim that the seven bases $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}, \{Te_1,Te_2,Te_3\}, \dots, \{T^6e_1, T^6e_2, T^6e_3\}$ will give you a schedule of the kind you want (for any initial basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$). To see this, note that, as $T$ has order $7$, $A^n$ also has order $7$ for $n$ not a multiple of $7$. So, if $n,m \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with $m \neq n$, then any two vectors which differ by $T^n v$ for $v \in \{e_1,e_2,e_2+e_1\}$ must not also differ by $T^m v$ (or $T^{n-m}$ would fix $v$). So

- Two players cannot be on a team more than once.
- Two players cannot be opponents more than twice (once when they differ by $T^n e_2$, and once when they differ by $T^m(e_2+e_1)$).

But each player has one teammate and two opponents in each of the seven pairs of games, so it follows by counting that each player must have each other as a teammate *exactly* once, and as an opponent *exactly* twice.

If we use the $T$ given above, and start with the basis $\{001, 010, 100\}$, this gives the following schedule:

1. $000$ and $001$ vs $010$ and $011$; $100$ and $101$ vs $110$ and $111$ (basis is $\{001, 010, 100\}$)
2. $000$ and $110$ vs $001$ and $111$; $010$ and $100$ vs $011$ and $101$ (basis is $\{110, 001, 010\}$)
3. $000$ and $011$ vs $110$ and $101$; $001$ and $010$ vs $111$ and $100$ (basis is $\{011, 110, 001\}$)
4. $000$ and $111$ vs $011$ and $100$; $110$ and $001$ vs $101$ and $010$ (basis is $\{111, 011, 110\}$)
5. $000$ and $101$ vs $111$ and $010$; $011$ and $110$ vs $100$ and $001$ (basis is $\{101, 111, 011\}$)
6. $000$ and $100$ vs $101$ and $001$; $111$ and $011$ vs $010$ and $110$ (basis is $\{100, 101, 111\}$)
7. $000$ and $010$ vs $100$ and $110$; $101$ and $111$ vs $001$ and $011$ (basis is $\{010, 100, 101\}$)

---

Writing this in terms of your original letters, the schedule is

1. AB vs CD; EF vs GH
2. AG vs BH; CE vs DF
3. AD vs GF; BC vs HE
4. AH vs DE; GB vs FC
5. AF vs HC; DG vs EB
6. AE vs FB; HD vs CG
7. AC vs EG; FH vs BD

Notice that A always stays on the first field, while everyone else moves around (in the language of the abstract algebra from above, this is because A corresponds to the zero vector, which is fixed by any power of our order-$7$ isomorphism). You could probably mess with this a little bit (e.g., by swapping the identities of the fields every other time) but there's always going to be some asymmetry, since there are two fields and everyone's playing an odd number of games.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In effect, you are trying to create the complete graph on 8 vertices 3 different times.  First, we will address the matter of getting everyone to play with everyone else:

Let each person be a vertex on $K_8$.  Let two vertices be adjacent if the two corresponding players played together.  Note that in each of the 14 games, two new edges are made, one for each team.  This means that we have 28 edges in our graph on 8 vertices by the end of the tournament.  The size of $K_8$ is $\frac{7\cdot8}{2}=28$, which means that the tournament can fill out the entire graph.  This happens if each player plays in half the games, so their vertex has degree 7.

Note that combinatorics does not discriminate based on whether or not you are on a team with a person, so by a symmetry argument we observe that it is, indeed, possible for each person to play against each other person two times (if we arrange the players in a $2\times 2$ grid, each player can play each other player once while directly opposing each other and once while diagonal to each other).

Comment: Thanks Tim, great! By what algorhythm has do the grids have to filled? Is there only one possible solution?