# Is it possible to arrange a tournament of 12 players with each teaming with each other once and competing against each other twice?

Tags: combinatorics

If there are twelve players, and each player is to be on a team of two with every other player exactly once, and also ends up competing against every other player exactly twice in 2V2 play, can such a tournament arrangement be made?

In a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552159/tournament-of-8-people-in-teams-of-two-everyone-teaming-up-once-and-competing-t) - an answer beyond my comprehension is affirmative for 8 players under similar conditions, but it's beyond me how to apply the answer to 12 players.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a tournament can be made. It is called a [Whist Tournament Schedule](http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/round-robin/rounds.php?it=12&v=w1).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible.  A schedule is shown [here](http://www.bridgeguys.com/pdf/Movements/IN/IN12P22B.pdf).  You start with 
$$ \begin {array} {c c c c c}Table&North&South&East&West\\
1&12&1&5&10\\2&7&11&8&9\\3&2&4&3&6 \end {array}$$
Then each player $1-11$ moves to where the lower number was last round.  Player $12$ stays stationary and $1$ follows $11$.  I haven't checked it carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unless I'm misinterpreting it, it seems for example player 5 plays against a team with player 8 only once but against a team with player 4 three times.

Comment: Yes, checking closely 5 never plays against 10 or 11.